# Facebook User ID of users seems to change after they give permission to my app, completely breaking my "App Requests"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, userid

We were just putting the finishing touches on our game when I ran into an issue with a new batch of test users on Facebook.

In my game, you can invite Facebook friends to your match via the request dialogue. After the user selects their friends, the app dialogue spits out a list of Facebook ID's that the they have selected. I add those users to the current match as 'pending' users and store their Facebook ID's somewhere in the database. At this point their Facebook ID's look fairly standard.

Let's pretend that I've invited *Test User 1* to the game via an App Request and stored their facebook ID in my database (100006********4).

Now, when that user sees the app request, they'll download my app and log into it with their Facebook account. At this point they are asked to grant my app permission to their account. After they accept, their Facebook ID now becomes something completely different (303918********0). What's even stranger is that the I can't seem to find any users with the ID '100006********4' any more.

When I view the pending user list, I fetch the profile pictures and the names of those users. So in this case, my app attempts to fetch the profile picture/name of '100006********4', but Facebook no longer returns any information about that user. Fetching the profile picture/name of '303918********0' returns a valid result.

So now I have this issue where my game is waiting for this user that no longer 'exists'. I have no way to associate the pending users Facebook ID with their new ID.

I assume this has something to do with new app-scoped user IDs, but I am at a loss when it comes to fixing this problem.

The request dialogue does not seem consistent either - it will return a mix of facebook ID's and 'app-scoped user IDs'. That is, if I was to invite the user previously identified as '100006********4' to a new game *now that he has granted permission to my app*, the request dialogue will spit out '303918********0' as that users ID, rather than '100006********4' as it did before they granted permission to my app.

Comment: Yes don't do it that way. When someone clicks on a request and get sent to your app the url will contain the request id. And you store who sent that request

Comment: So is the target user ID embedded into the request ID the 'app scope ID' of that user? That is, if I invite user '100006********4', will the request ID generated be ***********_303918********0 ?

Comment: Doesn't matter what the request id is. You should just use it to lookup in your database who sent it

Comment: The purpose behind introducing app-scoped user ids is to keep apps from knowing to much about users that are not app users (yet). So in consequence you don’t get IDs from `invitable_friends` that you can later match to users who accept requests.

Comment: There is a bug that actually returns globally scoped IDs in the Unity3D Facebook SDK, and that is what was causing all my confusion. See my answer below for a link to the bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is a bug in the Facebook Unity SDK that returns global scope User ID's for users who have not yet logged into your app before. You can find more information here.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/614713991970823/)